# How to render cartoon style with completely flat colors?

Tags: shaders

How to render perfect cartoons in blender? Whatever the engine is (internal or cycles) I always get that shading transition somewhere on the model.

[image: Blender internal render engine]

[image: Cycles render engine]

*The first picture is in blender internal render engine with the toon shading material and the second picture is in cycles render engine with the toon shader.*

---

How can I get completely flat colors with no fancy shading variation?

[image: shading transition]

[image: no shading transition]

Comment: have you tried to add another lamp (Hemi) to your scene I don't get these pronounced shadows?

Comment: to stacker - I lowered the light bounces in cycles - min-1, max-2

Comment: I tried Light BWK's explanation, but I still get the same results.

Basically, I want to make a cartoon animation in cycles with completely flat colors.

Comment: Well.. okay. I thought your original example image kind of implied that this was part of your other question, but if it's not, then I guess this works as a separate question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way in Cycles would be to create a shader on the compositor that affects the overall rendering, or just the materials you want.

In this example the monkey on the right has a material with an index pass of 1.
In the compositor I'm using a color ramp to remap the shading. The two tone shading is achieved using constant as interpolation on the ramp.

[image]

The rest of the materials are unaffected by the ramp.

Comment: I really like that one, but the render time would be expansive.

Comment: not by a lot...

Comment: Why am I sent to this page when I want an entire scene to be cell shaded? Yet every example is just changing 1 material to ramp. That's not what I want.

Comment: @EricHuelin When commenting, at least add a link of the question/comment that is sending you here.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67323/can-a-light-make-ramped-shading

Comment: I just wish someone could show me how to use compositing to make a cell shaded images without ramp coloring materials. This example shows how to make orange and brown ramp on 1 object, that is not what I want. The below answers show how to use ramp materials, that is not what I want either.

Answer (score 20):

[image: base Toon/cell shading]

These are the settings you need to change to set flat toon/cel shading. To get rid of aliasing with constant interpolation, in options panel, turn on Full Oversampling. There are limitations, noted them in the graphic.

Answer (score 12):

In BI this can be done by using toon shading and setting the *smooth* value to 0, then feeding it into a color ramp:

[image]

I also disabled specular highlights by setting the specular intensity to 0.

Answer (score 10):

You can do something similar to cegaton's solution in Cycles by feeding the same type of ramp he used through the color input of a toon bsdf shader.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: This is a solution you do in the material, not the compositor.

Comment: This isn't even Freestyle! It's just the material node editor. (But you can definitely add that on top of this for better lines.) Freestyle is applied after everything is rendered, then added. I'm not sure if Freestyle is done before compositing, or not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ;). I meant to type "cell shading". I often mistype it 'cause they often go hand at hand in cartoons. Yeah, it is a compositing effect

Answer (score 7):

After some trial and error I created my BI toon shading setup in Cycles. This is a very simple and useful setup. You can easily decide light and shadow direction with lamp in scene and object shading with ColorRamp node. If you use this setup with Freestyle it can be nice looking cell shaded objects. And if you don't want to change shadow position while animating objects (which is I recommend it) parent your lamp the object.

Here is the my setup.
[image]

Comment: I like this.  Your node setup didn't work for me because in the Texture Coordinates node I was using a real lamp.  When I changed it to some non-lamp object (e.g., a sphere) then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I use the internal blender engine for cartoon style render all the time. if you don't want shadows on it in the material tab down in the shading section check the button beside shadeless and it takes away the shading and shadowing. also if you want a outline like a line drawing outline in the render tab check edge and adjust to the way you like it.

Answer (score 1):

I use this setup for EEVEE only.

[image]

When rendering turn on *Freestyle* to get outlines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Experiment with **Ambient Occlusion** and **External lighting** under the *World Settings Panel* for more toon like effects AND the **Stroke** & **Freestyle** (1 px is more than enough) settings under the *Render Section* for edge strokes and outlines on objects.