# How do I set an entire complex scene to look toon?

Tags: color

I don't want to set materials to be color ramped/toon look I want an entire scene and characters to look toon without having to change every material of every single prop in a complex scene.

Can I use a camera or light effect or even to have the camera look through a transparent plane or something that changes the entire scene to toon?

Comment: Which renderer are you using?

Comment: Do a search for [**freestyle** rendering](https://www.blender.org/manual/es/render/freestyle/introduction.html#what-is-freestyle). On the other hand you can also control the colors in the compositor. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10925/how-to-render-cartoon-style-with-completely-flat-colors/10938#10938