# Can a light make ramped shading?

Tags: light

With a scene that has no ramped materials and no toon materials, can a light source provide cell shading?

I wish for the final effect to look like the image below the light emits yellow and the shadows are blue. Everything has cell shading and anything put into the scene gets the same cell shading.

Preferably done in blender render if possible.

[image]

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10939/1245. This is done the same in BI.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10939/1245 Has nothing to do with what I want. I don't want to use ramp shaded materials. I have multiple characters and multiple props, cars, buildings, cities, I can't spend countless hours making ramps for hundreds of materials.

Comment: Explain better then. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10939/1245 is compositing, not materials setup and is done once regardless of the scene materials. In BI one material can be set up to rewrite any other one and any object added to scene will get its options. To make shadows blue change *Ambient Color* in World settings to blue. To make lamps shadows sharp for Spot lamp enable constant falloff in *Lamp*, set *Blend* to 0 in *Spot Shape*. To make lamp emit yellow make its color yellow.

Comment: When I read http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10939/1245 I see nothing there to help me make a scene that is completely cell shaded. That could be because I never used a node or composited anything in Blender until a week ago. To my untrained eye all I see is ramp materials explained.

Comment: Nodes are used not only on materials, but on compositing as well. The idea on the linked answer is that you take the rendered image and render it converting a range of tones to a more limited one. You can use this globally for your scene or if you have material index set to your objects, you can be more selective.

Comment: I know that nodes affect the output image as in compositing. But the linked page doesn't show me how to make cell shading using the compositor. I don't know how else to say it.