# how to achieve this mesh hair render (like in the new zelda) in blender internal/viewport render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

as the title suggest i just doesn't seem to be able to achieve this kinda style in blender is really hard to achieve (do i need to tweak the normal in this case).

Cheers Noob.

Comment: [How to render cartoon style with completely flat colors?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10925/2217)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render cartoon style with completely flat colors?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10925/how-to-render-cartoon-style-with-completely-flat-colors)

Comment: thanks for the info, but what i mean is how you make the fresnel, multi depth cel shaded look like the picture above 
(sorry if there is any disreparancy on this english is not my first language)