# How to render cartoon style in completely flat colors (with EEVEE)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

[How to render cartoon style with completely flat colors?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10925/how-to-render-cartoon-style-with-completely-flat-colors)

Hi there, Blender fella.
I just want to know how to achieve this kind of rendering result in EEVEE. I used Cycles Render to create this image long time ago.

[image]

I think the nodes are kinda like this. i forgot the detail.

[image]

I made that picture with Cycles Render, now i want to achieve the same (or maybe better) result with EEVEE. Any idea?

[image: Kneel before me, mortals]

Comment: The nodes are the same in the this two engine.

Comment: If you are using emission  nodes only, cycles will be incredibly fast as well.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Wrong picture. I going to edit the question for a moment.

Comment: Oh, i end up changing the whole question o_o

Comment: Sorry, mortals.

Comment: Found this https://youtu.be/QLSZRfcUiQI?t=77.

Comment: Thank you, Mice Terminator :)