# Comic book shader

Tags: scripting, materials, shaders

I just started using Blender slowly switching over from long time Maya use . .  I want to be able to control the gray values with image textures so I can create more detail in those areas . .  anyone interested in maybe sharing some info on how to achieve a comic book like style? thx in advance everyone! Here is what I have so far and trying to advance it  . .  so I can have more cross hatching [image: ial]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10925/how-to-render-cartoon-style-with-completely-flat-colors

Comment: You should look into the "Shader to RGB" node (Eevee renderer only) if you don't already have

Comment: Also could you share an illustration of the effect that you're trying to achieve?